# Is there a name for the following important group of line bundles with rational sections?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

Is there a name for the following important group of line bundles with rational sections, given by Vakil in [FOAG 15.4.3, page 436](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGmay2523public.pdf#page436)?

> **15.4.3. The important group of "line bundles with rational sections".** Now consider the set $\{(\mathscr{L}, \mathrm{s})\}$ of pairs of line bundles $\mathscr{L}$ with rational sections $s$ of $\mathscr{L}$, not the zero section on any irreducible component of $X$, up to isomorphism. (An isomorphism $(\mathscr{L}, s) \cong\left(\mathscr{L}^{\prime}, s^{\prime}\right)$ means an isomorphism of line bundles under which $s$ is sent to $s^{\prime}$.) This set (after taking quotient by isomorphism) forms an abelian group under tensor product $\otimes$, with identity $\left(\mathscr{O}_X, 1\right)$. (Tricky question: what is the inverse of $(\mathscr{L}, s)$ in this group?)
>
> It is important to notice that if $t$ is an invertible function on $X$, then multiplication by $t$ gives an isomorphism
> $$
> (\mathscr{L}, s) \stackrel{\sim}{\longleftrightarrow}(\mathscr{L}, st) .
> $$
> Similarly, $(\mathscr{L}, s) /(\mathscr{L}, u)=(\mathscr{O}, s / u)$. Here $s / u$ is a rational function.
> The map $\operatorname{div}$ yields a group homomorphism
> $$
> \operatorname{div}:\{(\mathscr{L}, s)\} / \text { isomorphism } \longrightarrow \operatorname{Weil}X$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: These should be closely related to Cartier divisors. Have you checked if the two notions agree in the irreducible case?

Comment: @Daniel Haven't checked the relationship with Cartier divisors yet. But Vakil gives an enlightening diagram in 15.4.10 saying that it's isomorphic to all the locally principal Weil divisors on normal Notherian schemes.

Comment: In that diagram, the Picard group is written as $\operatorname{Pic}X = \mathscr{L}/\text{iso}$. And the group in question here is written as $\{\mathscr{L},s\}/\text{iso}$. Maybe it is not important enough to own a name. After two days of thought, I think just calling it “invertible sheaves and rational sections quotient isomorphism” descriptively is OK too. :D

Comment: In that case, this group agrees with the group of Cartier divisors, since Cartier divisors can be identified with locally principal Weil divisors (see Hartshorne II.6.11.2, page 142) in the normal noetherian case. I strongly suspect that this identification holds for more general classes of schemes, since I think such rational sections usually embed $\mathscr{L} \hookrightarrow \mathscr{K}$.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah. From https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306234/different-definitions-of-cartier-divisor-and-when-they-agree, I see that some texts use it as the definition for Cartier divisors, and in most cases, it coincides with the other two definitions (one in the above link and another one in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087674/why-do-we-have-two-definitions-of-cartier-divisor)